# Can't handle JSON response with ajax bind success

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a simple calculation using a form with `AJAX`. The form sends the parameters, the controller receives it, do the calculation and return the result.
The results are all the expected and I can see them in the shell but can't send this to the view.

I'm using `data-remote="true"` in the form, so I'm returning the `JSON` like this:

```
def calculator  
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: result_plano, status: :ok }
  end
end
```

And the `jQuery`:

```
$("#calculator").bind("ajax:success", function(data){
  alert(data);
});
```

But it keeps returning `undefined`

Comment: Have you verified that `result_plano` is returning results? Also, you might have to call `to_json` on that unless it's already being converted

Comment: Yes, it's returning results. I've just skipped this part of the code

Comment: What happens if you replace `alert(data);` with `console.log('something');`?